# M3 AV1 hardware decoding requirements (encoding options, pixel format etc.)

Tags: video, apple-silicon, encoding

Are there any restrictions on the encoder options, pixel formats, etc. that can be decoded by the M3 AV1 hardware decoder? For H264 and H265, only a subset of the bitstream options are accepted, both for hardware accelerated playback and any use within TV.app or QuickTime.

I can't find either an official list on Apple's website or a list of successful settings in ffmpeg's wiki.

Comment: Which practical problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: I’ve got a some really inefficient videos that I want to reencode with a modern format and good-quality software compression. As I expect to be buying an AS Mac in the next year or so, it makes sense to use AV1 instead of H265, but I want to use a format that will be compatible with the Apple ecosystem going forwards.